# Facebook on Mac Opera - blank pages, errors in Developer's Console

Tags: macos, javascript, opera, facebook

Since few days I encounter issues with Facebook...
I am unable to see Notifications, Messenger... I even don't have the 'publish' widget present on my fanpage.

Opera Developer's console contains following logs:

```
Opera has modified script or content on www.facebook.com (PATCH-1195, Facebook - block first character in the comment field from triggering a single key keyboard shortcut). See browser.js for details
```

And error with callstack:

```
/notifications:1 Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'autofill_test' of undefined
at setAutoFillAlgorithmState (chrome-extension://hnjalnkldgigidggphhmacmimbdlafdo/onloadwff.js:58:227159)
at LP_setval (chrome-extension://hnjalnkldgigidggphhmacmimbdlafdo/onloadwff.js:58:169021)
at fillfield (chrome-extension://hnjalnkldgigidggphhmacmimbdlafdo/onloadwff.js:58:161444)
at chrome-extension://hnjalnkldgigidggphhmacmimbdlafdo/onloadwff.js:58:120257
at r (chrome-extension://hnjalnkldgigidggphhmacmimbdlafdo/onloadwff.js:58:5475)
at Object.apply (chrome-extension://hnjalnkldgigidggphhmacmimbdlafdo/onloadwff.js:39:40)
at chrome-extension://hnjalnkldgigidggphhmacmimbdlafdo/onloadwff.js:58:106817
```

Issue looks just like that:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5csv9.png)

Anyone has any idea how to solve it?

- MacOS Mojave 10.14.1
- Opera 56.0.3051.116

Thanks!